# Transform nested arrays of integers into a flat array of integers - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, dashboard

The work context of my question is **data visualization**. 
It is correct transforming nested arrays of integers into a flat array of integers in this way?

```
var inputArray = [[1, 2, [3]],4,[5, [6, [7,8],[9]]],10];

var inputArrayStr = inputArray.toString(); 
var outputArrayInt = JSON.parse("[" + inputArrayStr + "]");

console.log(outputArrayInt); // --> [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
```

Comment: _"It is correct transforming nested arrays of integers into a flat array of integers in this way?"_ What is expected result ?

Comment: [[1, 2, [3]],4,[5, [6, [7,8],[9]]],10] --> [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]

Comment: Well, it works, but depending on where this is being used you may want to avoid string manipulations for such work

Comment: You can json.stringify and then replace all the [ and ]

Comment: Should work if your array has only numbers and not commas `inputArray.toString().split(',')`

Comment: at this point I guess a solution both for string and numeric arrays should be the best solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually:

Take [`Array#flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) with [`Infinity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity) as parameter for a flat array of all levels:

```js
const
    input = [[1, 2, [3]], 4, [5, [6, [7, 8], [9]]], 10],
    output = input.flat(Infinity);

console.log(output);
```

---

Older Answer:

I suggest to use a special function for this task.

```js
function flat(a) {
    var b = [];
    a.forEach(function (c) {
        if (Array.isArray(c)) {
            b = b.concat(flat(c));
        } else {
            b.push(c);
        }
    });
    return b;
}

var inputArray = [[1, 2, [3]], 4, [5, [6, [7, 8], [9]]], 10],
    outputArray = flat(inputArray);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(outputArray, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

input array: `var inputArray = [[1, 2, [3]],4,[5, [6, [7,8],[9]]],10];`

result as string:

```
var stringResult=inputArray.toString();
```

stringResult => "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"

result as array:

```
var stringArray=stringResult.split(',');
var arrayResult=[];
for(var s in stringArray){
arrayResult.push(parseInt(s));
}
```

arrayResult => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Answer (score 0):

You can flat array step by step using Array.prototype.concat.apply.

```
function flat(arr) {
    var result = arr;
    while(result.some(Array.isArray)) {
        result = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], result);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(flat([[1, 2, [3]], 4, [5, [6, [7, 8], [9]]], 10])); 
// [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
```

To explain code above:

```
Array.prototype.concat.apply([], [[1, 2, [3]],4,[5, [6, [7, 8],[9]]], 10]) ;
```

is basically the same as:

```
[].concat([1, 2, [3]], 4,[5, [6, [7, 8], [9]]], 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern way

```
const flattenArray = (arr) => arr.reduce((prev, curr) => (Array.isArray(curr) ? prev.concat(flattenArray(curr)) : prev.concat(curr)), []);
```